# Golang return pointer to interface throws error

Tags: pointers, testing, go, interface, mocking

I have a basic function in Go that opens a file and tries to decode its JSON contents.

I am trying to extract the default `json.NewDecoder()` function so I can easily mock this in my tests.

However, my implementation seems to return an error:

> cannot use json.NewDecoder (type func(io.Reader) *json.Decoder) as type decoderFactory in argument to NewConfig

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

type openFile func(name string) (*os.File, error)

type decoderFactory func(r io.Reader) decoder

type decoder interface {
    Decode(v interface{}) error
}

type Config struct {
    ConsumerKey,
    ConsumerSecret,
    AccessToken,
    AccessTokenSecret string
}

func NewConfig(open openFile, d decoderFactory) (*Config, error) {
    c := new(Config)
    file, err := open("some.file")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error opening config file")
    }
    defer file.Close()

    decoder := d(file)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&c); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error decoding config JSON")
    }

    return c, nil
}

func main() {
    _, err := NewConfig(os.Open, json.NewDecoder)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "something bad happened: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Je1YR4AKZ1)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Decoder is a struct and not an interface in the json package, check here https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`json.NewDecoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder) is a function with the following declaration:

```
func NewDecoder(r io.Reader) *Decoder
```

Its return type is [`*json.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder). `json.Decoder` is *not* an interface, it's a concrete type. And 2 function types are different if their return type is different: [Spec: Function types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types)

> A function type denotes the set of all functions with the **same parameter and result types**.

So you can't construct a new type returning an interface, and expect to be the same as `json.NewDecoder`, or that it'll accept the value `json.NewDecoder`.

But the *"seemingly"* easy fix is: define your `decoderFactory` to be a function type exactly what `json.NewDecoder` is:

```
type decoderFactory func(r io.Reader) *json.Decoder
```

This compiles, ok... but how to mock now?

#### How to mock now?

Of course in this form, you'll lose the possibility to mock `json.NewDecoder()` (because a "mocker" would have to return a value of type `*json.Decoder` and nothing else would be accepted). What to do then?

You have to use a different factory type. The factory type should be a function which returns an interface (of which you can provide different implementations), you were on the right track:

```
type MyDecoder interface {
    Decode(v interface{}) error
    // List other methods that you need from json.Decoder
}

type decoderFactory func(r io.Reader) MyDecoder
```

But you can't use `json.NewEncoder` *as-is* to pass as a value of `decoderFactory`. But fear not, it is very easy to create a function of type `decoderFactory` which will call `json.NewEncoder()` under the hood:

```
func jsonDecoderFact(r io.Reader) MyDecoder {
    return json.NewDecoder(r)
}
```

*We're mocking the behaviour of `json.Decoder`, and not the `json.NewDecoder()` factory function.*

Using this `jsonDecoderFact()`:

```
_, err := NewConfig(os.Open, jsonDecoderFact)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "something bad happened: %v\n", err)
}
```

This is valid and compiles, because `jsonDecoderFact` has exactly the same type as `decoderFactory`.

If you want to test / mock with a different implementation:

```
type TestDecoder struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (t TestDecoder) Decode(v interface{}) error {
    // Test / mocking logic here
    return nil
}

func testDecoderFact(r io.Reader) MyDecoder {
    return TestDecoder{r}
}
```

Using it:

```
_, err2 := NewConfig(os.Open, testDecoderFact)
if err2 != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "something bad happened: %v\n", err2)
}
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_7TImaNEkR).

Comment: I thought duck typing would resolve this issue? As *json.Decoder implements decoder

Comment: @TimBlackwell Unfortunately not.

Comment: @TimBlackwell duck typing works for matching inputs to method parameter types, and returns to return types.  It doesn't, however, work for function signatures.  In other words, if Foo is a concrete type, and Foo fulfills Bar, then F() Foo and F() Bar are still two different function signatures.  The reason behind this is that, if a function returns a Foo, and you instead give it a Bar, what if it expected to be able to access the fields of that returned value?  Now it can't, because it's a Bar, and might not even be a Foo at all!